# Creating Column Chart with DC.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I want to create a column chart with [DC.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js) like below image : [image]

and my Data is like this :

```
var data =[
  {name:'Venezuela',sale:300},
  {name:'Saudi',sale:253},
  {name:'Canada',sale:150},
  {name:'Iran',sale:125},
  {name:'Russia',sale:110},
  {name:'UAE',sale:90},
  {name:'US',sale:40},
  {name'China',sale:37}
]
```

i try to create but i don't know exactly what happen.i don't know how to draw x-Axis or y-Axis.i search and find some example,but in that examples all the x-axis is time sole it use `.x(d3.time.scale()` but my x-axis is not time and i don't know how to control it.

**Update**

adding color to chart

```
 var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['#DB0A5B','#F62459','#F1A9A0','#2C3E50','#26A65B','#E87E04','#D35400']);
 chart.colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range(colorScale);
```

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is here.  For the x scale you would use `.x(d3.scale.ordinal())` (and don't forget `.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)`).  It might help if you posted a jsfiddle with what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick sample to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/s9c84/

```
chart
.height(300)
.width(800)
.dimension(countryDimension)
.group(countryGroup)
```

As Gordon said, you need to set an ordinal scale:

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(countries))
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

Here is how you can manage the axis labels:

```
.xAxisLabel("MMbbl = one million barrels")
.yAxisLabel("Reserves (MMbbl)")
.elasticY(true)
.xAxis().ticks(3);
```

This will get you to a graph like this:

[image]

Like Gordon mentioned, you will need to use a renderlet to control there colors.  The example fiddle is updated with this code:

```
 chart
    .renderlet(function(chart){
        debugger;
    var colors = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(countries)
        .range(["steelblue", "brown", "red", "green", "yellow", "grey", "blue", "black"]);
    chart.selectAll('rect.bar').each(function(d){
         d3.select(this).attr("style", "fill: " + colors(d.data.key));
});
```

Comment: Think you would need to use a renderlet to get the bars to be different colors, though. Currently each stack (layer) is assigned a color.

Comment: i try to add color with `chart.colors()` but it doesn't work. can you please give an example. thanks. i'm update my code that for my trying.